# How do large iOS development companies manage their Apple Developer accounts?

Tags: ios

I am curious how large development firms manage their Apple Developer accounts. I know they limit each account to 100 devices (and removing devices only takes effect once a year).  However, if your company has 40 developers who each have two devices, and you also need to share it 1 or 2 devices per client, you quickly run out of devices.

I realize that there is an option for an Enterprise account, but that solves a different problem than the one I am referring to.

1. Is it OK to create multiple developer accounts for this purpose?
2. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to create multiple developer accounts. What we do is that each developer has an Apple developer account and generates their own development certificate. In the main corporate account (the team agent account), we create development and distribution provisioning profiles used by everyone. Apple has a [clear and helpful guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html) on setting up a multi-developer team.

Each dev's certificate is added to the development profile; this means that every dev can use this development profile to run the app on their phones. Xcode will by default pick up their development certificate associated with this profile (if the code signing identity in project settings is set to "Automatic Profile Selector" > "iPhone Developer").

Unfortunately for the distribution profile though, you cannot really add any other certificate except the *distribution* certificate you created from your corporate account. A simple workaround to this is to just share the complete distribution certificate (public+private key and cert) with any developers that should have the ability to create a distribution build for the app (for a small team like ours, we just share the distribution cert with everyone). You can easily export this certificate from Keychain Access.

Once the dev(s) have added this distribution certificate to their keychain, this too will automagically be selected by Xcode during a distribution build (provided the code signing identity for the relevant build configuration is set to "iPhone Distribution").

Apart from this, I am not really aware of how you can get past the 100 device limitation, since all the devices have to be added to one account (the corporate/team agent account).

Comment: Its important to note that both the Enterprise and Developer programs limit the number of devices that can be registered for development testing to 100.  These devices can be connected to a Mac and have software deployed and tested on them from within xCode without a distribution cert, you just need a development cert.The main difference between the two programs is that you can freely distribute apps under the Enterprise program to your employees within your network but cannot deploy via the app store.  You need the Developer program membership to deploy to the app store.

Answer (score 5):

Creating multiple accounts to get around the device limit is a violation of the Developer agreement:

*(I was going to quote the developer agreement here, but after 30 minutes of searching, I can not find the agreement on the dev site or itunesconnect, but I remember it had a clause in there about not creating multiple accounts)*

**Update:** You can petition Apple to increase your device limit.

There are different types of developer accounts.  The enterprise account has a higher device limit, but I'm not sure what that limit is.  I think it is 500.  With an enterprise account you can also setup a pseudo-appstore for internal distribution.  http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the enterprise account solves a different problem.  There is a big difference in the two account types.

Comment: @dtuckernet Yes, there is a big difference.  I know of at least one company that has two accounts to get extra devices and Apple hasn't terminated their either/both of their accounts yet.  But it would be within their rights to do so.

Comment: Agreed - which is why I like Chaitanya's response.  By working with accounts that the individual developers own, you gain the ability to do more.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the process for petitioning Apple to increase the device limit? Do you have experience or have you had people directly inform you that they have been successful in this? Just curious.

Comment: @Duncan It is mentioned in the developer agreement (which I still can't find online even though I signed it digitally).  I don't know anything about the process of doing so.

Comment: @DuncanBabbage You have your Team Agent call Apple Developer Support at 1-800-633-2152 and a HUMAN will answer within 3 rings. O_O

Comment: @IronMensan The Enterprise Developer agreement has the same limit as the regular developer agreement - 100 devices for ad-hoc testing can be registered.  Under enterprise program, you can distribute freely to any employee of your company but for testing devices, you are limited to 100, just like the normal developer program.

Comment: I believe the 500 limit IronMensan is referring to is the fact that now all accounts have 100 devices of each type (iPhone, iPad, Apple TVs, Macs, iPods).  That is the same for developer and enterprise accounts.  The difference with enterprise accounts is that is allows for an In House Distribution profile that doesn't require devices to be registered by their UDID

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question might add my two cents worth after going through this at my organisation.

We have two accounts, enterprise and standard for distribution through the iOS store, each account has max 100 (not sure if this was different earlier but thats our current limit). Most developers are added to the enterprise account.

Unless you have a massive amount of developers and I doubt any would if they think about it only developers should have their devices on the account. Once it needs to go to clients or shared not for public use we use ad-hoc distribution which doesn't count towards your device id's.

We also petitioned Apple for more devices and we got an additional 10 which didn't really solve the problem.

With regards to the private key, you should never distribute it. It's a major security vulnerability.

Comment: "Once it needs to go to clients or shared not for public use we use ad-hoc distribution which doesn't count towards your device id's."
Doesn't count towards your device id's? what does that mean?
 For ad-hoc distribution you need a provisioning to cover the adhoc device, thus you need to add the device... So it must count, in one of the two accounts right?

Comment: @LolaRun Nope, it doesn't count towards your account ID's. We've done it a few times now. In theory you can actually create your own store, though Apple would invalidate your certificate in a second.

Comment: Yep thank you. That is because it's an enterprise account... right? And the enterprise account has a huge number of devices ... right?

Comment: The Enterprise account still has a limit of 100 devices for development purposes but it also allows you to distribute 'ad-hoc'. The devices you install your app on through 'ad-hoc' don't count towards your 100 devices and there is no limit.

Comment: @Rudiger can you elaborate on this? All literature I can find indicates that the limit of 100 applies to Ad-Hoc profiles.

Comment: @Rudiger I think you are referring to the unlimited ad-hoc capability of the Enterprise account profile. So e.g. if I only have the single user regular $99 dev account, I can still only add up to 100 devices whether ad-hoc or not.

Comment: @StevenLu Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Rudiger so if a company has an enterprise account, they can distribute ad hoc to an unlimited number of devices? we have a closed test user group under NDA of 300 users (employees and actual customers). what is the best approach?

Comment: @miraculixx Yes, when you distribute via the ad hoc enterprise account, devices you install the App on don't count towards your 100 development device limit. Just read the full T&C for the enterprise account to find out it's limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for enterprise accounts is also 100 devices and creating multiple accounts to overcome the limit is against apple's TOS. So the best way to go is to give a developer account (this is for testing) for each developer in the company and make releases through a specific centralized developer account.

Comment: Actually - this is not true.  There isn't a hard cap on devices in the Enterprise iOS Developer account.  This is different from an enterprise that has a regular iOS Developer Account.  For more info see this: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: True. Enterprises that have a regular account have a cap of 100 devices but with an actual enterprise account there is no cap.
The difference is with a regular account you can do both ad-hoc and appstore distribution. Whereas in enterprise accounts you can distribute apps via ad-hoc only.
Hence companies who distribute apps on the appstore use multiple accounts as i have stated above.

Comment: Ahmed is actually correct - BOTH the Enterprise and Developer Programs have a limit of 100 registered development devices.  Its important to note that these are REGISTERED devices for DEVELOPMENT.  The Enterprise Program allows you to freely distribute apps to "employees" which has a very specific definition in the legal agreement you sign with Apple.  I'm wondering if this is where the confusion is for this 100 device limit - 100 devices for testing but unlimited distribution as long as its distributed to employees, under the Enterprise program.