# Multiple iOS developer licenses for a company

Tags: ios, licensing, udid

My company has an iOS developer license, and like many others we have reached the 100 UDID limitation.
Since I have about 10 more months until the next time I can delete unused UDIDs I tried purchasing another IOS developer license for my company but got rejected from Apple since my company already holds a program enrollment.

How can I bypass this issue? I really need more UDIDs so I can send my applications to testers. Do I need to open an individual iOS programing license or is there another way to enroll a company to another iOS license.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do Large iOS Development Companies Manage Their Apple Developer Accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260791/how-do-large-ios-development-companies-manage-their-apple-developer-accounts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This has been covered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260791/how-do-large-ios-development-companies-manage-their-apple-developer-accounts) None of the answers look particularly appealing, but I doubt you'll get other advice.